# Pub transformer with test dependencies

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I have a dart package (Harvest) that contains a dev (test) dependency on polymer which I use only for integration testing purpose

```
  dev_dependencies:
    polymer: "^0.16.4+1"
    test: any
  transformers:
  - polymer:
      entry_points:
         - test/harvest_idb_test.html
```

However in order to run the polymer tests I need to register a polymer transformer. Running this transformer fails unless I move the polymer dependency into the projects main dependencies which I really want to avoid as its only needed for testing purposes.

Is there a way to register a transformer that depends on a dev dependency or can I somehow create a **dev_transformer** section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `$include` to only include files in your test directory, then you can leave it as a `dev_dependency`. The transformer won't attempt to load when your package is used as a dependency of other packages. For example:

```
dev_dependencies:
  polymer: "^0.16.4+1"
  test: any
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
      - test/harvest_idb_test.html
    $include: test/**_test{.*,}.{dart,html}
```

Answer (score 2):

Such a request was declined here
- https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1260
- https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/925

using `$include/$exclude` was mentioned in both as a workaround but that doesn't solve your issue.

There is also https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1324 merged into https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1183 which is marked as fixed. This looks like it should work.

I would create a new issue in the pub repository.